# Sequence of real numbers converge to complex number

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it possible to have a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that each $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ but $\displaystyle \lim_{n} x_n \not \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @njguliyev, I think your comment should be the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 6):

The limit of a convergent sequence of complex numbers must converge with respect to real and imaginary parts separately. Using that you can see that what you ask is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x+iy$ be the limit. Then for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $n$ so that

$$|y| \leq \sqrt{(x_n-x)^2+y^2} = |x_n-z| < \epsilon \,.$$

As $|y| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ we get $|y| \leq 0$ and hence $y=0$.